# Paste cell values rather than formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am searching multiple sheets for a string, once this string is found it copies it to the MergedData sheet.

The problem i am having is it is coping the formulas rather that the value. I have been searching for hours and cannot seem to find a solution.

Here is the code that i am using at the moment.

Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Thanks Aarron

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FirstAddress As String, WhatFor As String
Dim Cell As Range, Sheet As Worksheet
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

WhatFor = Sheets("SUB CON PAYMENT FORM").Range("L9") 


Worksheets("MergedData").Cells.Clear


If WhatFor = Empty Then Exit Sub


For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Sheet.Name <> "SUB CON PAYMENT FORM" And Sheet.Name <> "MergedData" _ 
    And Sheet.Name <> "Details" Then


With Sheet.Columns(1)
   Set Cell = .Find(WhatFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)


If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
   FirstAddress = Cell.Address
     Do
     Cell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MergedData").Range("A" & Rows.Count)_
     .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     Set Cell = .FindNext(Cell)
    Loop Until Cell Is Nothing Or Cell.Address = FirstAddress
End If
End With
End If

Next Sheet

Set Cell = Nothing  
End Sub
```

Comment: I can give you the code but you may want to try recording a macro and doing a paste special values and see what code the macro spits?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but with support from someone else i have managed to get it to work.

Comment: Answer your own question! (You get a badge :))

Comment: And now i'd like to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from others all i had to do was replace.

```
Cell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MergedData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

With this:

```
Cell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MergedData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `range.copy` method with a destination, but use only copy and use `PasteSpecial` with `XlPasteType = xlPasteValues`

[Range.PasteSpecial Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839476%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I am a newbie at VBA and am still learning. I have tried that, but where i am searching a string across multiple sheets i couldnt get that type of code to work, the code i have is a result of weeks or trial and error and it was the first one that worked. If you know of a better way to do it, i would appreciate the help.